# Returning animated image to original position

Tags: javascript, animation

I've been working on a very simple animation script. The images are to move when clicked, stop when clicked again, etc. I have this all working fine. The trouble is I have a stop everything button below the images which is suppose to not only stop the images but to return them to their original position. So far it stops, but it doesn't return.

I've searched and found a few different solutions, however this is a university assignment and I am NOT allowed to use Jquery.

This is my script:

```
var timer = null;
var cat = null;
var dog = null;

function moveOver1Pixel()
{
    cat.style.left = parseInt(cat.style.left) + 1 + "px";
}

function moveOver10Pixels()
{
    dog.style.left = parseInt(dog.style.left) + 10 + "px";
}



window.onload=function()
{
        //MOVE CAT FUNCTION
        cat = document.getElementById("cat");

        cat.onclick=function(){
            if(timer == null)
            {
                timer = setInterval("moveOver1Pixel();", 100);
            }else{
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
        }


        // MOVE DOG FUNCTION
        dog = document.getElementById("dog");

        dog.onclick=function(){
            if(timer == null)
            {
                timer = setInterval("moveOver10Pixels();", 30);
            }else{
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
        }


        // STOP BUTTON FUNCTION
        document.getElementById("stop").onclick=function()
        {
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
            reset = true;
        }


}
```

and this is the html portion I am using:

```
<img src="cat.jpg" id="cat" style="height:100px;position:absolute;left:10px">
<img src="dog.jpg" id="dog" style="height:100px;position:absolute;left:10px;top:110px">

<input type="button" value="EVERYONE STOP" id="stop" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:220px">
```

I feel like the solution to my problem should be simple... something I'm missing inside of the button's onclick function? Or am I going to have to create an entirely new function for the reset/return of the images to their original place?

Comment: in your stop function you need to either set style.left to 0 or remove it. right now you're only stopping the movement.

Comment: Not sure if you wanted animated return to start or immediate, so I put the animated ones in a comment. I changed a lot of the style too to help you learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a lot:

```
var timer, cat, dog, ticksCat = 0, ticksDog = 0,
moveOver1Pixel = function(inc){
    cat.style.left = parseInt(cat.style.left) + inc + "px";
    // Don't change if inc is -1, ~-1 === 0 == false
    if(~inc) ticksCat+=inc;
},
moveOver10Pixels = function(inc){
    dog.style.left = parseInt(dog.style.left) + inc*10 + "px";
    if(~inc) ticksDog+=inc;
};



window.onload=function(){
    //MOVE CAT FUNCTION
    cat = document.getElementById("cat");

    cat.onclick=function(){
        if(!timer){
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                moveOver1Pixel(+1);
            }, 100);
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    };


    // MOVE DOG FUNCTION
    dog = document.getElementById("dog");

    dog.onclick=function(){
        if(!timer){
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                moveOver10Pixels(+1);
            }, 30);
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    };


    // STOP BUTTON FUNCTION
    document.getElementById("stop").onclick=function(){
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        reset = true;
        // to do immediately
        while(ticksCat--){ moveOver1Pixel(-1); }
        while(ticksDog--){ moveOver10Pixels(-1); }

        /* animated
        while(ticksCat--){ setTimeout(function(){moveOver1Pixel(-1)}, 100*ticksCat);}
        while(ticksDog--){ setTimeout(function(){moveOver10Pixels(-1)}, 30*ticksDog);}
          Multiplication on time is to synchronously set a queue of async moves            
        */

    };


};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This concept has been a bit confusing for me. There's another similar question on the assignment that your modification will help me with as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
document.getElementById("stop").onclick=function()
{
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
    reset = true;
    document.getElementById("cat").style.left = "10px"
    document.getElementById("dog").style.left = "10px"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is actually something like what I'd originally been trying to do. it WORKS, but it seems to toy with the movement and onclick of both the images in some browsers. I can click on either image for them to move and stop instead of individually.

Comment: Actually, this does seem to work for what I need... thank you for providing a simple solution; also makes me feel less discourages because I almost figured this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = null;
var cat = null;
var dog = null;

function moveOver1Pixel()
{
cat.style.left = parseInt(cat.style.left) + 1 + "px";
}

function moveOver10Pixels()
{
   dog.style.left = parseInt(dog.style.left) + 10 + "px";
}



window.onload=function()
{
    //MOVE CAT FUNCTION
    cat = document.getElementById("cat");

    cat.onclick=function(){
        if(timer == null)
        {
            timer = setInterval("moveOver1Pixel();", 100);
        cat.startLeft=cat.offsetLeft;
        cat.startTop=cat.offsetTop;
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    }


    // MOVE DOG FUNCTION
    dog = document.getElementById("dog");

    dog.onclick=function(){
        if(timer == null)
        {
            timer = setInterval("moveOver10Pixels();", 30);
        dog.startLeft=dog.offsetLeft;
        dog.startTop=dog.offsetTop;
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    }


    // STOP BUTTON FUNCTION
    document.getElementById("stop").onclick=function()
    {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        reset = true;
            if (typeOf cat.startLeft !=undefined)     
        {
        cat.style.left=cat.startLeft+"px";
        cat.style.top=cat.startTop+"px";
        }
    if (typeOf dog.startLeft !=undefined)
        {
        dog.style.left=dog.startLeft+"px";
        dog.style.top=dog.startTop+"px";
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern and "proper" solution to would be to use css transitions to handle the animation while using JS to control the position:

```
var cat = document.getElementById("cat");
var dog = document.getElementById("dog");

cat.addEventListener('click', moveIt);
dog.addEventListener('click', moveIt);

function moveIt()
{
    this.style.left = "400px";
}

// STOP BUTTON FUNCTION
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener('click', function()
{
    cat.style.removeProperty('left');
    dog.style.removeProperty('left');

    //Uncomment for instant-reset
    /*
    cat.style.transitionDuration = dog.style.transitionDuration = '0s'; 

    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        cat.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
        dog.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
    }, 250);
    */
});
```

With your css looking something like this:

```
#cat, #dog
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    transition: 10s left linear;
}

#cat
{
    left: 25px
}

#dog
{
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

See this JSFiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SPHMM/3/.  Of course, if the assignment is specifically to do all the animation in javascript, this probably doesn't count.  But for real life applications, this should provide the best quality, lowest cpu usage animation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I actually really like this way, as I'm very comfortable working with css. I'm going to hold onto this.